# Holo theme on API Level < 11

Tags: android

I would like to use Holo theme in my app, but the minimum API level for Holo theme is 11.

My question is, what will happen if an app with Holo theme is installed on a device with API level lower than 11?

Will the app crash, will just design be messed up, or something else?

Comment: Use versioned resources: `res/values/` to hold a style resource that inherits from `Theme`; `res/values-v11/` to hold a style resource that inherits from `Theme.Holo`. Android will choose the one from `res/values-v11/` on API Level 11+ devices, and will choose the one from `res/values/` on API Level 10 and below. The new-project templates at least used to set up this structure for you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it will crash if you are using only that theme because that theme does not exist. you can use third party libraries that can create the look of holo but without that you are out of luck.

You can use different layout folder with different themes based on the android version the device has

Answer (score 0):

I think there is an library for that.
http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2012/01/holo-everywhere.html?m=1

Answer (score -1):

Use [AppCompat](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html) to use holo themes in APIs < 11

Comment: AppCompat provides an action bar, but not holo themes, for API Levels 7-10.